# Appending a selected-state using JQuery in React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to append an active state in a React JS component when it is clicked.

Lets say I have a function

```
onMenuClick(e)
```

And my css class is called

```
.hamburger
```

I want to check the condition:

```
onMenuClick(e) {
  if (this.state.menuOpen){
  //append 'is-active' to the hamburger class    
  }
}
```

What is the most React-friendly/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) as the official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) suggest.